# 'lightningd.sqlite3' and 'emergency.recover' are binary files, why use diff then?

Tags: backup, core-lightning, static-channel-backups

[It is written in the documentation for core-lightning](https://lightning.readthedocs.io/BACKUP.html):

> Copy the contents of the $LIGHTNINGDIR to the BTRFS mount point.
>
> Copy the entire directory, then chown -R the copy to the user who will run the lightningd.
>
> If you are paranoid, run diff -r on both copies to check.

`lightningd.sqlite3` and `emergency.recover` are binary files, as evidenced by `file --mime-encoding`. Is `cmp` a better tool than `diff` for checking integrity of channel backups? Isn't `diff` preferred for text files and `cmp` for binary files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to know whether or not two binary files have identical contents, diff will do the job

See [How to compare binary files to check if they are the same?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12118403/477035)